# Behaviour of routing in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5.1

After trying out this [acl tutorial](http://heera.it/laravel-5-1-x-acl-middleware#.Vk_DaXarTGJ) I came across something I can't understand.

In laravel I created my route according to the tutorial and changed it to match laravel's auth controller (as I already used that before by installing it with [bestmomo](https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold)) to:

```
$router->get('/', [
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin',
    'as' => 'admin.user.login',
    'middleware' => ['acl:login']
]);
```

Like this it doesn't find my route giving me the error

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

If I add the following route:

```
Route::get('/login', [
'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'
]);
```

It works well.

Why do I need to add the second route?
Why can't the first one stand alone?

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Comment: no not yet, having another problem. SO I have to fix this first and then I can check your solution

FatalErrorException in User.php line 15:
Declaration of App\User::can() must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable::can($ability, $arguments = Array)

Comment: You have to make sure that `can()` method signature matches the interface `Authorizable`

Comment: that's my problem, I don't know where or how to do that

Comment: well if you are using vanilla laravel you wouldnt have this problem. So what code have you added/updated that implements `Authorizable`?

Comment: please join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95866/behaviour-of-routing-in-laravel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95867/discussion-between-gaz-edge-and-davejal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the blog you are following has an error.

The correct way to call a route you need is:

```
Route::get('/', [
   'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin',
   'as' => 'admin.user.login',
   'middleware' => ['acl:login']
]);
```

Note: you can also use a helper method and just call:

```
get('/', [
   'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin',
   'as' => 'admin.user.login',
   'middleware' => ['acl:login']
]);;
```

The only way I can see the the code you mentioned working is if the following is at the top of the routes file:

```
$router = app('router');
```

Comment: with this solution I'm missing the whole point of the acl tutorial ... or I'm missing the point you're making. Where will `'middleware' => ['acl:login'] `get in action?

Comment: this is exactly what I have in my question

Comment: no, you don't. You have $router->get. Not Route::get –

Comment: oops, sorry, will check and get back at you